# Is there way to fetch all requirements from polarion project using webservices

Tags: polarion

How to fetch all requirements from polarion with its linking and data and history using webservices?

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible via WebServices, the performance will be *very* low.
even if you are talking about "only" 1000 Workitems with approx 100 Revisions each, you will need at least 100.000 Request to the webservice API also as the links form a graph, you may visit and revisit WIs more often than once so more realistic (depending on the link structure) you end up with 500.000 requests.

On a good day you make maybe 10 Requests per second (a positive estimate), you end up needing more than 12 hrs to generate this data.

You should write a dedicated Servlet which can directly access the Polarion API to gather this data and outputs the data you are interested in(there is an servlet example in the SDK documentation).